# How to change highcharts opacity on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I change the opacity of a point on hover in Highcharts?

I am currently using the following, although it is very slow and laggy since I am running the points hex colour to convert it to RGBA. I am using a [heatmap](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap) chart type.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function () {
                    var newColor = hexToRgb(this.color);
                    var formattedColor = "rgba(" + newColor.r + "," + newColor.g + "," + newColor.b + ",0.7)";
                    this.oldColor = this.color;
                    this.update({
                        color: formattedColor
                    });
                },
                mouseOut: function () {
                    this.update({
                        color: this.oldColor,
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any easier approach to this?

Comment: So you want to keep the color, just with a different alpha value?

Comment: @Ondkloss - Correct, to make the opacity lower upon hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no out of the box change opacity for the hover. You can apply brightness, but that is slightly different.

The part I believe is slowing you down is not the conversion, but the constant `update` and redrawing. One possible workaround for all this work is to do it immediately after the chart is ready, and then never do it again.

An example of this would be the following code in the callback function of the chart construction:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    // Options
}, function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.series[0].data.length; i++) {
        var point = this.series[0].data[i];

        // Set the hover-color for each point once upon creation of the chart
        point.update({ 
            states: { 
                hover: { 
                    // Use the old color and change the opacity to your liking
                    color: Highcharts.Color(point.color).setOpacity(0.3).get() 
                } 
            } 
        }, false);
    }
    // Redraw once instead of on every hover
    this.redraw();
});
```

See [this JSFiddle heatmap demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/uteqzxfn/) of how it looks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an illusion in the referred [heatmap demo page (themed one)](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap/sand-signika).

It seems that the theme applied only the first `colors` value as the hover color of the heatmap point.

So try adding this:

```
    colors: [null],
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/uteqzxfn/1/

If necessary, you can change the border color which override by the `colors` value.

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderColor: '#303030'
        }
    },
```